# Browsing is painfully slow

Tags: performance

Either it's Firefox or Chromium - browsing is painfully slow for some reason. It just takes lots of time to do anything: open a tab, load a website, etc. My internet is really fast and other programs run fast, but the browsing is really too slow. What can I do?

btw, I ran htop, it shows that these 2 browsing programs take lots of CPU, sometimes over 100%.

Also, the same thing happens in Xubuntu and Ubuntu.

I have 3GB RAM. And previously it worked much better.

Comment: @karel: Yes, I have 3GB. And previously it worked much better. Everything else runs extremely fast.

Comment: When you say that previously it worked much better, do you mean in 13.10?

Comment: @kikjezrous month ago maybe

Comment: please post the results of the following command `ping -c 10 www.google.com` this will tell us what your actual internet speed is... What is your CPU, Wifi/LAN chip?

Comment: 7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.595/35.666/35.827/0.127 ms

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen how to know that sorry?

Comment: you can find the specs for your cpu under (system settings > about system), as for the wifi/lan, im not sure, but the model of your PC can be googled, and a hardware spec sheet found (usually on the manufacturers website)... i guess a model number would give all these details... that is usually on the bottom of your PC (i have an Asus K55A)

Comment: the ping output tells me the problem is not a slow internet connection (i receive similar results from a ping command)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        P6200  @ 2.13GHz

Comment: dell inspiron m5010

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleared your browser cache(s)? For Firefox, there are [instructions on the Mozilla website.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache) For Chrome, you can find [instructions on Google's chrome page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en).

Try that, then either log out and in, or reboot, and see if it helps. If it does help, then you might want to reduce the limit of your browser cache size. In Firefox, you type "about:config" in the address bar, and then set the value of "browser.cache.disk.capacity" to the smaller value you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to diagnose what might be happening is to temporarily create a new user, log in as the new user and run the browser. If you don't experience any performance issues, you know it's a (user) local issue related, for instance, to misconfiguration or corrupt/invalid cache.